# Redux state not changed after updating the initial state

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a react native app with redux and auth state and reducer

```
const authState = {
    token: 'sample-token',
    id: undefined,
    username: undefined,
    email: undefined,
    mobile: undefined
}

const authReducer = (state=authState, action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case "LOGIN":            
            state = {
                ...state, token: action.payload.token,
                id: action.payload.id, username: action.payload.username,
                email: action.payload.email, mobile: action.payload.mobile
            };
            break;         
        case "LOGOUT":
            state = {
                token: '', id: '', username: '', email: '', mobile: ''
            };
            break;        
    }
    return state;
}

export {authReducer};
```

Initially the authState initital state was:

```
const authState = {
    token: '',
    id: '',
    username: '',
    email: '',
    mobile: ''
}
```

But, whenever i do console.log(this.props.auth) in any of my views, I get the output of the old state and not the one with new data.

```
console.log(this.props.auth)
Output: token: "", id: "", username: "", email: "", mobile: ""}
```

Comment: Can you also post the component calling the dispatch functions

Comment: this state looks like state after LOGOUT action dispatched. Are you sure your LOGIN action dispatched correctly?

Comment: please post the complete code.. what is this.props.auth?

Comment: @Andres fixed it by adding the default case to the switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not exporting the authReducer function correctly and not returning state correctly in switch statement.
Try the function like below,

```
    const authReducer = (state=authState, action) =>{
        switch(action.type){
            case "LOGIN":            
                return {
                    ...state, token: action.payload.token,
                    id: action.payload.id, username: action.payload.username,
                    email: action.payload.email, mobile: action.payload.mobile
                };         
            case "LOGOUT":
                return {
                    token: '', id: '', username: '', email: '', mobile: ''
                };
           default:
               return state;    
        }
    }

export default authReducer;
```

Comment: I had been exporting the function. Apparently, I have to add a default case to the switch statement!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are dispatching the action for the corresponding action type ?
If not do the following

```
export const login = () => {
  return {
    type: LOGIN,
    payload: { id: 1, username:'bla bla' }
  }
}
```

and import the action in your view and dispatch it

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onLogin : () =>
            dispatch(login())
      }
  }
```

and call it like this.props.onLogin()

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by adding the default case to the switch statement. Apparently, if I do not add the default case, it will return the state of the last case.